# pass infiormation between component in localstorage

Tags: angular, local-storage, state

I a use case where there is informations that i have to pass over many components  , I tries ngrx to pass informations over global state but it doesn't work  fine  for me ,also  when user refreshthe page the state will be deleted   .  is there any problem  if I'll pass these informations over local storage since it's not  sensitive information  ?
thanks

an advise   or sharing experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your idea, you can create a service that will be responsible for managing this data (reading from local storage, setting it if data is not set) and use it whenever you want, just make sure that you will retrieve this data from one service and not calling to local storage in different services, components.

Comment: thanks  , finally I  changed the structre of the app  , and I'm using routable components and passing data  over urls   , BUT this solutuon can be used  when the routable component will not be a possible option